# Why delegate method is not called?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I am trying to notify ChatViewController that a chat was deleted in MessagesViewController using a protocol, but the delegate method implemented in ChatViewController is never called.
In the navigationController hierarchy  ChatViewController is on top of MessagesViewController.

```
protocol MessagesViewControllerDelegate:class {
  func chatWasDeletedFromDatabase(chatUID: String)
}

class MessagesViewController: UITableViewController {
    weak var delegate: MessagesViewControllerDelegate?

  func observeChatRemoved() {
    print("it is gonna be called")
           //inform ChatViewController that a chat was deleted.
   self.delegate?.chatWasDeletedFromDatabase(chatUID: chat.chatUID)
    print("was called here") //prints as expected
  }
}


  class ChatViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {

     var messagesVC: MessagesViewController? 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

     messagesVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
     messagesVC?.delegate = self
   }
 }


    extension ChatViewController: MessagesViewControllerDelegate {
    func chatWasDeletedFromDatabase(chatUID: String) {
    print("chatWasDeletedFromDatabase called") //never prints out
      if self.chatSelected.chatUID == chatUID {
         //popToRootViewController
       }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems

```
weak var delegate: MessagesViewControllerDelegate?
```

is `nil` you have to set it to the `ChatViewController` presented instance what ever how you present it

```
let chat = ///
self.delegate = chat
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chat,animated:true)
```

Also do

```
chat.messagesVC = self
```

as this

```
 messagesVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
 messagesVC?.delegate = self
```

isn't the currently presented messagesVC ,  so comment the above 2 lines

Comment: `ChatVC` is already presented by `MessagesVC`. I don't understand your explanation. ChatVC defines a protocol, MessagesVC adopts the protocol and sets itself as the delegate. in `viewDidLoad` with `messagesVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessagesViewController") as! MessagesViewController
        messagesVC?.delegate = self` . The delegator, MessagesVC should send the data, to the delegate, namely  ChatVC.

Comment: Question for someone with more experience than me. Do you prefer making a delegate optional or forced-unwrap. I answered a question today, explaining that my preference is to use `var delegate: MessagesViewControllerDelegate! = nil` precisely because of this. Any sort of runtime testing will immediately expose the issue. I'm sure there are advantages to your preference. What's are they?

Comment: @bibscy you want to send information from messagesVc to chatVc , so you use delegate var inside the messageVc which should has a non-nil reference to the chatVc , also the 2 lines you commented will create another instance of the messageVc not the really one you navigated from to the chat ,,,,,, so when you push chatVc you should store a reference to it that will enable you to call the method that it adopts

Comment: @dfd Optional since it would not crash the app.

Comment: @Sh_Khan I understand now. The reason why I was confused is because so far I only used protocols to send data from a custom tableView cell to tableViewController and I never had to set in the tableView cell class `self.delegate = instance of tableView`

Comment: your implementation is reversed , the usual way is we use it when want to send information say from chat to messages , that' why the way is some strange

Comment: @dfd optional way is not to crash the app for a mess setup , so since you're the developer if you know that the delegate will always has a non nil value then use **!** otherwise **?** should be in place the important is to make it **weak**